# Using symbol links with dlopen()

Tags: c++, plugins, shared-libraries

I'm working on an object-oriented C++ project that:

1. Uses a large amount of RAM.
2. Has a large amount of disk input/output on start up.

During normal operations, the software performs very well. However, new versions are slow to release because of the above two factors (a minor update requires the software to be restarted).

As I said, it's an object oriented system, with objects appearing and disappearing constantly. What I would like to do is have my objects loaded from a shared library, which is a symbolic link to the current version (e.g., `libthing.so -> libthing.so.1`). This way, I can change the symbol link (e.g., `libthing.so -> libthing.so.2`) so that the next object loaded into memory is the latest version, with the latest logic (it doesn't matter if some of the existing objects have older logic, as they'll eventually be purged from the system).

However, the above symbolic link strategy isn't working for me. The same version of the library is used even after changing the symbolic link. Is what I want to do possible?

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be related to the filename of the shared library. If I call `readlink()` prior to calling `dlopen()`, `libthing.so` is resolved to `libthing.so.1`. After this call, having multiple versions of the library open simultaneously works as expected.